# Change Password Control RegEx validating oddly in IE 7 only

Tags: asp.net, regex, internet-explorer-7, regex-lookarounds

I'm using the Asp.net change password control in my application and all seems to be find and dandy until a user tells me she has a problem meeting the strength requirements when changing her password. Looking into this, she is using IE 7 and no matter what she puts in, the validation fails (and ONLY in IE 7. Firefox, IE 8, Chrome etc. all work as expected). Here is the regex i'm using:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).{5,15}$
```

I've tried out a few others that I've found throughout this site and others that folks seem to be using with no issues and I come across the same problem.

It seems that which ever pattern I enter in last (digit, upper or lower alpha) is the one that is expected to be repeated min of 5 times. For example:

`Hello1` (doesn't work)

`11111Hello` (doesn't work)

`Hello11111` (works)

Again, this is ONLY in IE 7. I've spent too much time on this already and I'm stumped. Anybody have any ideas??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently Internet Explorer has a bug. Check out this post: [A JScript/VBScript Regex Lookahead Bug](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/regex-lookahead-bug). The example is the same - a password check - and they provide a work-around. Using their suggested approach as a guide, the pattern becomes:

```
^(?=.{5,15}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).*
```

Their pattern is very similar to yours, except for the negative look-around for whitespace.

---

Try using `.*` in the look-arounds. Using just `.` only covers one character followed by whatever you're specifying in the look-arounds. You want to look all the way ahead and see if anything matches. I tried the following expression in Expresso and it worked with the samples you listed and also failed on invalid inputs as expected.

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).{5,15}$
```

Comment: interesting, I do have the * in my regex but somehow it was dropped when I posted. I didn't notice that.

Comment: thanks! I tried variations, putting the 5,15 up front but never got it quite right. this was a good post explaining the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Internet Explorer __is__ a bug.