# Asp.net RegularExpression Validation not working properly

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to use the ASP.NET regularexpressionvalidator to apply a password policy that enforces the following policy:

Password should include at least 6 characters, at least one small letter, at least one Capital letter, at least one number, and at least one special character. Here is the expression:

^.*(?=.{6,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=*!-_()?]).*$

The strange thing I found is that it works fine except with the following scenario,

If I use all the required combination without special character such as Hello123" it finds it as valid password. below is the controls used for testing:

Any idea why?

Comment: is it finding Hello123" as valid or **invalid**? Looks like your post may have lost content when posting.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem recently. Are you only seeing the problem in IE? You could be running into the [regex lookahead bug](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/regex-lookahead-bug).

check out my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518232/change-password-control-regex-validating-oddly-in-ie-7-only) and maybe it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys,
I found the problem. The special characters need to be escaped..

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you:
(?=^.{6,}$)((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9]))^.*

I am using it in an Asp.Net regular expression validator control to validate passwords with the same requirements that you have for your passwords.
The only problem is that I think it will allow the field to be empty, so I also use a required field validator.
Unfortunately I don't know enough about regular expressions to figure out why yours doesn't work.