# Password regex works in chrome and firefox, but not IE7

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, regex, client-side

The following regular expression works in chrome and firefox, but not IE7:

`^((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,20})$`

It needs to contain at least 8 characters and have at least on uppercase and a number. When I try this in IE7, I have to type 14 characters for it to validate.  Can someone explain why and what would be the correct expression for all 3 browsers.

I am using an asp:RegularExpressionValidator to validate the password.

Comment: *Confused*. This is tagged as C# and ASP.NET, so presumably this regex is running serverside and the browser is irrelevant? If this is javascript, please tag it as such.

Comment: Well, the regex is an asp:RegularExpressionValidator which is client-side validation.  I believe by default, the regex is run client-side unless I specify a Server-side validate event handler.  Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: If the issue is in IE but not firefox, it *must* be running on the client. Do you even know what HTML/JS source is being generated? Methinks you need to do more learning that just "regex".

Comment: To clarify, the asp:RegularExpressionValidator will generate javascript code that runs client-side. The actual validation is thus done in javascript. I suggest you look at the generated javascript code and try to simplify it to see where it's going wrong in IE.

Comment: I just used your Regex and it worked in IE 7/8 with Asp.net RegularExpression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

been asked before:

[Change Password Control RegEx validating oddly in IE 7 only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518232/change-password-control-regex-validating-oddly-in-ie-7-only)

Answer (score 0):

```
str.length > 8
/[A-Z]/
/\d/
```

Three checks vs. one monster regex. Which is easier to read and doesn't cause issues in IE?

```
if( str.length > 8 && str.search(/[A-Z]/) != -1 && str.search(/\d/) != -1 )
{
   //Don't use big long regex when you don't need it
}
```

Comment: Im new to regex, so I am a little confused by your answer.

Comment: The solution is to use less regex.

Comment: @Xaisoft: He's saying you should do three simple checks instead of trying to come up with just one regular expression. Newbies to regular expressions sometimes believe that regexes can solve anything, or that using one is the most optimal solution. As Stefan Kendall's answer shows, it is far simpler to just do each check individually: first check the string length, then check for the presence of one uppercase letter, then check for the presence of a digit. (You can also check for only alphanumeric with a further check like this: `^[A-Za-z0-9]+$`)

Comment: I understand what he is saying, but I don't understand how to transform is answer into an asp.net regex.

Comment: but what is more of an issue is why does this work fine in chrome and firefox, but fail in IE7.

Comment: If you're having issues in IE but not firefox, this is a javascript issue. I'm not quite sure you know what you're doing.

Comment: I updated my post to say that I am using an asp:RegularExpressionValidator which I believe uses client-side validation unless you give it a server-side validation function to call, so it does use javascript.  I just marked it asp.net and c# because that is what I am working with.

Comment: I wonder why this was voted down. It may not address why the regex is broken in IE, but it's very good advice from my point of view. The code posted in this answer is 10 times more readabale than a gigantic regex. Regexes are cool but way overused. Take both approaches and you understand Stefan's code in 5 seconds. You'll probably have to think for over 3 minutes while researching lookarounds online.