# IE7/IE9 javascript incompatibility problem

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change Password Control RegEx validating oddly in IE 7 only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518232/change-password-control-regex-validating-oddly-in-ie-7-only)

I am using this expression I picked up from a website to validate a password. It works fine in FF and IE9 but flags the pw as incorrect when it's not, in IE7.

```
var pwval = /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?!.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?!.*\s).{6,8}$/;

if (!pwval.test(mu.pw.value)) {
    alert('Your password must satisfy the following. \n\n* Password should be 6 to 8 character long. \n* Password should have at least one alphabet. \n* Password should have at least one numeric value. \n* Password should not have special characters.');
}
```

Any ideas anyone?

John

Comment: BTW, passwords should be allowed to contain special characters and be longer than 8 characters...

Comment: @RoToRa is correct. If you follow the regex changes in the original question, it will work in IE7. BTW, it is also currently broken in IE6.

Comment: Max 8 chars and no special chars? I hate sites like that, but "should have at least one alphabet" made up for it tho. ;-)