# Regex failing in IE7 only

Tags: javascript, regex

I have created a regular expression for password field validation check with the following rules:

1. At least a lowercase char
2. At least a uppercase char
3. At least a special char
4. At least a numeral

The regex: `/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,}$/`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: Also you are making use of look ahead functionality here which is not supported in IE 7

Comment: @Arun P Johny read the title

Comment: This has been asked before, [Change Password Control RegEx validating oddly in IE 7 only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518232/change-password-control-regex-validating-oddly-in-ie-7-only).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest work-around is not to use look-ahead at all. In your case, since all look-ahead starts from the beginning of the string (due to `^`), it is equivalent to check each of the look-ahead separately. You can further remove `.*` and go for an unanchored match.

```
if (/[a-z]/.test(str) &&
    /[A-Z]/.test(str) &&
    /[!@#$&*]/.test(str) &&
    /[0-9]/.test(str) &&
    str.length() >= 8) {

    // All conditions met
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Applying the same concepts as suggested in [Change Password Control RegEx validating oddly in IE 7 only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518232/change-password-control-regex-validating-oddly-in-ie-7-only), you'll end up with the following regex:

```
/^(?=.{8,}$)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9]).*/
```

I don't have IE7 so I can't test it though.